# How to top level filtering in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

There are 10-digit numbers from a1 to a50.
I want to filter the ones whose 3rd digit of 10-digit number is 7.
how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Excel365` then try-

```
=FILTER(A2:A16,MID(A2:A16,3,1)=7&"")
```

[image]